# Virtualenv not activating in Windows 10 PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell

I'm having trouble activating the virtualenv in Windows as I am going through the basic book of Learning Python the Hard Way.  Here is what I am getting:

> PS C:\Users\Owner> virtualenv --system-site-packages .venvs/lpthw
>
> Using base prefix
>   'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python36' New
>   python executable in C:\Users\Owner.venvs\lpthw\Scripts\python.exe
>   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
>
> PS C:\Users\Owner> ..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate
>
> ..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate : The term
>   '..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + ..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: `virtualenv --system-site-packages ".\.venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate"` ?

Comment: I tried that and got: ERROR: File already exists and is not a directory.  Please provide a different path or delete the file.

Comment: Well then try `virtualenv --system-site-packages ".\.venvs\lpthw"`

Comment: @Paxz I tried that code and got the PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission Denied.  I then ran virtualenv --system-site-packages ".\.venvs\lpthw\activate" and it created a new base prefix and executable.  I then ran .\.venvs\lpthw\scripts\activate (the original) and it worked....I'm not sure why? Could you explain to improve my knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

Is your virtual environment path incorrect? I see that you have gone back into the Users directory at the start of your command with

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> ..venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate
```

But it also appears that you created the virtual environment in the Owner directory.

Try:

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried that code and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you typed in an incorrect path when you tried to activate the virtualenv (double dot).
I am not a PowerShell expert since I use UNIX-based systems, but something like `.\.venvs\lpthw\Scripts\activate` should work for you.

Comment: Thank you PierreOcinom.  For some reason that \ did not show up when I posted to Stack Overflow.  The error came from the path exactly as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simply because the command "activate" is a batch file and expects to be ran from a Command Prompt, not a PowerShell prompt. PowerShell execution is done differently than batch file execution.

Search your virtual env provider for Activate.ps1, and either edit the batch file to run that instead, or create a function in your PowerShell profile to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error when I was trying to activate the environment. I created that environment with vscode terminal. But when I reopen the vscode and run the activate command again, I was successfully able to activate it. So, I guess sometime it need to restart the editor to activate the newly created environment.